# Windows API - GetTimeZoneInformationForYear not returning correct information for requested year

Tags: vba, windows, api

I'm trying to implement a set of classes and collections in VBA (Microsoft Access) to load up all the Time Zones worldwide and their historical information in order to do calculations for historical date time conversions to UTC. To do this I'm using the Windows API.

I've got EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation and GetDynamicTimeZoneInformationEffectiveYears seemingly working correctly.

However, when I try to get the information for the underlying years using GetTimeZoneInformationForYear, the information in the returned TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure seems to only ever contain the current values for the requested Time Zone, never the values from the requested year.

Has anyone else experienced this problem (regardless of programming language), and if so, have you solved it, and if so, how did you do so?

TIA

Edit to add declarations:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation Lib "advapi32" (ByVal dwIndex As Long, lpTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" (pDynamicTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDynamicTimeZoneInformationEffectiveYears Lib "advapi32" (pDynamicTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, FirstYear As Long, LastYear As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" (lpTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformationForYear Lib "kernel32" (wYear As Integer, lpDynamicTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, lpTimeZoneInformation As tyAPI_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Public Type tyAPI_SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Public Type tyAPI_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As tyAPI_SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As tyAPI_SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Public Type tyAPI_DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As tyAPI_SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As tyAPI_SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
    TimeZoneKeyName(0 To 127) As Integer
    DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled As Long
End Type
```

Comment: Are you API declarations correct (32 vs 64bit)?

Comment: Edited post to add code declarations for functions and types

Comment: Clearly you ought to mention the year, time-zone and locale you have trouble with.  As well as what you used as an oracle, there is a lot of bad info out there.  But have a look at what to expect, run Regedit.exe and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Time Zones.  The "Israel Standard Time" zone is a good one, rules are a political negotiation every year.  That's the year range you can expect to be covered (2004-2023), years before or after use the current rule.  Google "vba olson tz database" for extended coverage.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling a bit today. The TZ I'm using to check against is Fiji Standard Time, and I've used the Registry entries for it to know that it's got 2008 to 2029 on my PC, and that the FirstYear and LastYear returned by GetDynamicTimeZoneInformationEffectiveYears are correct.

Comment: Fiji in 2008 in registry has no values (all zeros for Std and Dlt). 2009 has 1st Thurs in January for Std, and 5th Sunday in November for Dlt. Yet what comes through the TZI from GetTimeZoneInformationForYear is for the main TZ entry in the registry, 3rd Sunday in January for Std, and 2nd Sunday in November for Dlt. (remembering that Fiji is Southern Hemisphere so the changes are opposite to Northern Hemisphere time zone DST adjustments).

Comment: `wYear As Integer` => `ByVal wYear As Integer`.

Comment: @GSerg if you add that as a reply, I can mark it as the answer, as that seems to have fixed it. Thanks! It's so annoying when the API documentation doesn't explicitly say that a variable should be by value.

Comment: It does. [`USHORT wYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformationforyear) is unambiguously `byval as integer`, otherwise it would have been [`PUSHORT wYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#PUSHORT) or `USHORT* wYear`. I have voted to close as a typo though.

Comment: I don't know 'USHORT wYear' means ByVal, again that's an implicit interpretation. I'm not a coder in non VB6 / VBA, so other languages aren't something I find easy to interpret. I have to go by examples of VB6 / VBA that others have posted elsewhere on internet, as MS don't supply VB6 or VBA information on their help pages.

Comment: There are many languages that support pointers, providing examples for all of them would be silly. WinAPI signatures are given in the C language, once and for all; the assumption is that you are able to read and understand C and correctly translate pointer and non-pointer arguments to the corresponding constructs of the language that you are using. The VBA construct for "pointer" is "ByRef".

Comment: @HansPassant I have a feeling that your statement '...years before or after use the current rule...' might not be correct. For U.S. time zones such as 'Alaskan Standard Time' there are dynamic DST entries for 2006 and 2007, that fit with the principle that 'up to 2006' is one setting, and '2007 and after' is the next setting, that happens to also be the current setting. I don't believe the current setting applies to 2005 and before. Can anyone else confirm the rules for before and after the dynamic DST years?